# String encoding of Arabic characters in UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, arabic

An Arabic name shall be sent via SOAP. The name is encoded like this:

```
<value>&#217;&#133;&#216;&#173;&#217;&#133;&#216;&#175; &#216;&#185;&#216;&#168;&#216;&#175;&#216;&#167;&#217;&#132;&#217;&#132;&#217;&#135; &#217;&#135;&#217;&#132;&#216;&#167;&#217;&#132;</value>
```

However when converting the above to UTF-8 with some online converters the result looks like this:
Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯ Ø¹Ø¨Ø¯Ø§Ù„Ù„Ù‡ Ù‡Ù„Ø§Ù„

What am I missing here so that the correct Arabic characters are displayed?

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoded data you showed **does** encode the nonsensical data you showed (or similar, because it actually encodes some unprintable characters as well).

So your **input** is already wrong.

You might be able to salvage it, but the correct solution would be to make sure that the input is correct in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the hint... I was not aware that the input may be wrong as it comes from a component not under our responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

This has been the problem Sending `UTF-8` data from Android. Your code would work fine except that you will have to encode your `String` to `Base64` . At Server you just decode `Base64` `String` back. It worked for me. I can share if you need the code.